# Alter character restriction on get_description()

Tags: simplepie

Just set up simplepie and is working superb, I would like to alter what appears to be a number of characters restriction on the get_description() output, I cannot find anywhare how I can alter this anywhere using the latest version 1.3

I appear to be getting approx 240 characters of the post content for the output then a "... continue reading" link, I would like to remove this link and increase the character output to say 400.

Any ideas how I cna go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the issue (eventually) within Wordpress (RSS feed from blog) and installed a plug in to increase the standard excerpt length and hey presto!